# C++: Use recursion to find the POSITION of the smallest value in a string?

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, position

How can I use recursion to find the POSITION of the smallest value in a string? The only 2 parameters I'm allowed to have are the array and its size.

Comment: Why would you use recursion to do this?

Comment: @tobi303, probably Homework.

Comment: @anon123  What is the string and what is its smallest value? If the string is a zero terminated character array then it is entirely unclear why the function has to have two parameters instead of one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The two-parameter restriction requires you to use a little trick: since you are not allowed to add the index as a third parameter, use length instead. You will be comparing the result of recursive run to the last element of the range `0..length-1`.

The reasoning goes like this:

- If the array has length of 1, return the index of the initial element
- Otherwise, run the algorithm for `length-1`, and compare the value at the index returned from the recursive invocation to the value of the last element (i.e. at index `length-1`)
- If the last element is smaller, return `length-1`
- Otherwise, return the index obtained from the recursive invocation

Answer (score 0):

If it is a plain array, you can modify the pointer (and decrese the size accordingly ) to get "sub-arrays" to pass to the next recursion level. Something like this:

```
size_t minpos(int *arr, size_t length)
{
    if(length < 2) return 0;

    size_t pos1 = minpos(arr + 1, length - 1);

    if(arr[pos1] < arr[0]) return pos1 + 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are required to find the smallest character in a character array that contains a string then it is entirely unclear why the function must have two parameters. Usually such algorithms that deal with strings have to have only one parameter.

So I have written a function that has only one parameter and returns the smallest character excluding the terminating zero.

Here is the function

```
#include <iostream>

size_t min_character( const char *s )
{
    if ( s[0] == '\0' ) return 0;

    size_t n = min_character( s + 1 ) + 1;

    return ( s[n] == '\0' ) || !( s[n] < s[0] ) ? 0 : n;
}

int main()
{
    const char *s = "anon123";

    size_t n = min_character( s );

    std::cout << n << ": \'" << s[n] << '\'' << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4: '1'
```

because the smallest character in the given string is character '1' and it has poistion 4 starting from 0.

With two parameters the function can look like

```
size_t min_character( const char *s, size_t n )
{
    if ( n == 0 ) return 0;

    size_t i = min_character( s + 1, n - 1 ) + 1;

    return ( i == n ) || !( s[i] < s[0] ) ? 0 : i;
}
```